# VBA matching Pairs without Duplicates

Tags: vba, excel

What I have been asked to do is take a users input as an integer. For example, 6 is the input. 6 gets passed into an equation (6 - 1)*(6)/2 this equates to 15 pairs. I then call another sub that processes the input into a set of {for next} loops. I have an If statement that checks duplicates but it is limited. I have tried passing in the iterative variable into the if statement but this will not work properly.

Here is the code:

```
For intOuter = 1 To options - 1

    'The intInner loop cycles through and sets up the loop for the combination and determines if
    'the combination has been made already

        For intInner = 1 To options

    'If statement tests if a combination has already been made if it has it will not be printed
    'if it has not been combined then it will be printed to the immediate window


                If intOuter <> intInner And intOuter <> value + 1 And intOuter <> value + 2 And intOuter <> value + 3 _
                And intOuter <> value + 4 Then
                       Debug.Print intOuter & " vs " & intInner & "  Actual"
                End If

        Next intInner

    Next intOuter
```

The output for this example correctly displayed would be (with a user input of 6)

```
1vs2
1vs3
1vs4
1vs5
1vs6
2vs3
2vs4
2vs5
2vs6
3vs4
3vs5
3vs6
4vs5
4vs6
5vs6
```

Thanks in advance I really Appreciate it.

Comment: It seems like you just want intInner to be bigger than intOuter...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you were close!  Try this:

```
   Dim intInner As Integer
   Dim intOuter As Integer

   For intOuter = 1 To Options - 1
       For intInner = intOuter + 1 To Options
          Debug.Print intOuter & "vs" & intInner
       Next
   Next
```

Comment: Thanks, @BrianMStafford I knew I was close I think I was looking at this to0 long and my brain over thought it. I really appreciate the help.